# RAND() function in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, random, sql-server-2014, newid

Can anyone help me to understand how to use RAND() function in SQL Server?

I have a scenario in which I want to fetch random products from products table in a random order on the basis of rating.

Also, in this I want to give preference to higher rating products over lower rating products to come at top order.

But it would not be like everytime only higher rating products will come at top in the order; sometimes lower rating products should be on top.

As of now, I did it through `NEWID()`, which gives me random order every time, but it doesn't consider ranking of products.

Table columns: `ProductID, ProductName, Rating`

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID() ASC) AS ProductOrder, ProductID, Rating
FROM dbo.VIHC_Products
ORDER BY ProductOrder
```

This query gives me random products everytime but does not fullfil my criteria of getting higher rating products at top over lower rating products most times.

Comment: so you want 'random but not _too_ random'? feels like an oxymoron... but you should be able to search for _SQL Server weighted random_ or similar and find existing questions.

Comment: "But it would not be like everytime only higher rating products will come at top in the order; sometimes lower rating products should be on top." - MAGIC? YOu need to define what you mean with "sometimes": Computers do not work with "sometimes", you need to define EXACTLY what you wants. "Most of the time" is something programmers laugh at - it is a term used by managers to avoid defining things. What do you mean with this?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a Stratified Sampling.  There are many techniques and methodologies for this. One of my favorites is Triangular Distribution.  This is where you get a random value between the Min, Max, and Most Likely.

Comment: @tomtom: If you don't know how to get it then can't you please avoid it?

Comment: @john thanks for your suggestion. I will work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiply the row number with the rating and order descending:

```
SELECT Rating * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID() ASC) AS ProductOrder, ProductID, Rating
FROM dbo.VIHC_Products
ORDER BY ProductOrder DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @Wouter , by using your suggestion below query helps me to acheive this:

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT))*Rating DESC) AS DealerOrder, 
   , ProductID, Rating
FROM dbo.VIHC_Products 
ORDER BY ProductOrder DESC